# Show partial not responding to coffeescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript

I am using **rails 3.2.17** and ruby 1.9.3p484.

Gemfile:

```
group :assets do
  gem 'uglifier',                               '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'jquery-rails'
  gem 'coffee-rails'
end
```

My application.js requires:

```
//= require_self
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.form
//= require jquery.ui.all
//= require jquery.ui.sortable

//= require froogaloop
//= require redactor-rails
//= require redactor-config

//= require vimeo
//= require s3upload
//= require s3_direct_upload
//= require permission_check

//= require jquery.livequery
//= require local
```

Model name is episodes

I made a new JS file named episodes.js.coffee

my _show.html.erb is not responding to coffeescript / javascript / jquery. I've tried adding my JS code to application.js and also tried putting //= require episode on my application.js

It only works when I put JS code directly on views.

Any idea whats causing this?

Comment: Do you include your javascript file in the html file?

Comment: by <%= javascript_include_tag('episodes.js.coffee') %> ? I get template error

Comment: @user2612713 where are you including this tag? which layout are you using for your my_show method?

Comment: I tried including it on _show.html.erb

Comment: @user2612713 you can't add this tag in your partial i.e _show.htm.erb. You need to add this tag in your layout file

Comment: I tried <%= javascript_include_tag('assets/javascripts/episodes.js') %>
 and <%= javascript_include_tag('episodes.js') %> on top of my index file, this is where I am including my show partial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i mentioned it in my comment, you can't include a javascript_include_tag inside your partial, its proper place is in layout as that's where you *head tag* is. You can write page specific js though.

In your case you need to just write `//= require_tree .` inside your application.js file. It will automatically include all of your js files and if you want to specify your js files individually then you can do `//= require episodes` inside your application.js file